# x86 asm program to find f=x^2-1 negated or zeroed depending on value of x

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I was tasked with writing x86 asm code that would output:

- (-x^2 + 1) if x is <= -1;
- 0 if the absolute value of x is less than 1;
- (x^2 - 1) if x >= 1.

This is what I came up with:

- The first problem is that in the first case the result isn't negative. If I input -3, it results in 8 and not -8.
- Secondly, if the value of x is less than 1, e.g. 0.5, it outputs -0.75 instead of 0.

I'm a beginner at assembly and this got me a bit stumped, so if you could help me get it to work correctly, I'd really appreciate it.

**Here's the code:**

```
extern printf, scanf
global main

section .data 
  in_fmt  db "%lf", 0
  out_fmt db "Result: %lf", 10, 0
  
  one dq 1.0
  minus_one dq -1.0

section .bss
  x resb 8
  f resb 8
  temp resb 8
  
section .text
main:
  mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging
  ;scanf()
  mov rdx, x           
  mov rcx, in_fmt       
  sub rsp, 40            
  call scanf
  add rsp, 40
  
  fld qword[x] ;x (input) is pushed on stack
  
  
  ;if x <= -1
  fld qword[minus_one] ;-1 and x are on stack
  fcomi
  jle case1
  
  fstp qword[temp] ;x is on stack
  
  ;if |x| <= 1 
  fld qword[one] ;1 and x are on stack
  fcomi
  jle case2
  
  
  case3:
    fstp qword[temp] ;x is on stack
    fmul qword[x] ;x*x is on stack
    fsub qword[one] ;x*x + 1 is on stack
    fstp qword[f] ; stack empty
    jmp print
  
  case2:
    mov qword[f], 0
    jmp print
  
  case1:
    fstp qword[temp] ;x is on stack
    fmul qword[x] ;x*x is on stack
    fmul qword[minus_one] ;-(x*x) is on stack
    fadd qword[one] ;-(x*x) + 1 is on stack
    fstp qword[f] ;stack empty
    
  print:
    mov rcx, out_fmt
    mov rdx, qword[f]
    sub rsp, 40
    call printf
    add rsp, 40
    
  xor rax, rax
  ret
```

Comment: Please add comments to each floating point instruction with what you believe is on the floating point stack at that point.

Comment: Also, what operating system are you programming for?

Comment: Note that the floating point argument should also be passed in `xmm1`. See [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170#varargs)

Comment: Hi, I will add the comments, also I’m programming for x64 windows using sasm

Comment: You have the comparisons reversed. You want `jae` not `jle`.

Comment: Also, this is x86-64, normally you'd want to use SSE2 `mulsd` / `addsd`.  Especially if you're not going to use useful x87 instructions like `fabs` as part of checking `|x| <= 1.0`.  (You can easily do the same thing with SSE2, using `andps xmm0, [mask]` where `mask` is `(1<<63) - 1`).  I think you can optimize it to `copysign(x^2 - 1, |x|-1.0)` plus a check for `|x| - 1.0 <= 0`.  `copysign` with SSE math is just a matter of `andps` to isolate the sign bit and `orps` to apply it to a known-non-negative value.

Comment: Anyway, single-step in a debugger and look at register values.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you! That is very helpful and I will take everything into account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a debugger to single-step your code and look at registers.  Also, FP branching uses the same conditions as unsigned integers, like `jae`.  But you don't need to branch here, if you spend some time coming up with a more efficient way to compute the result.

This is x86-64; normally you'd want to use SSE2 `mulsd` / `addsd` for scalar FP math.  Especially if you're not going to use useful x87 instructions like `fabs` as part of checking `|x| < 1.0`.  (You can easily do the same thing with SSE2, using `andps xmm0, [mask]` where mask is `align 16` / `mask: dq (1<<63) - 1` to clear the sign bit).

I think you can optimize it to `copysign(x^2 - 1, x)` plus a check for `|x| <= 0`. `copysign` with SSE math is just a matter of `andps` to isolate the sign bit and `orps` to apply it, since you only care about the case where the "target" is non-negative.  Otherwise you'd also `andnps` to clear the sign bit in the target to bit-blend the sign bit of 1 with the other bits from the other.

---

Unrelated to your FP logic, but `mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging` is weird without a `push rbp` before it. (And adjust `sub rsp, 40` to `32` to maintain stack alignment.) `main` is a function which should follow the calling convention, and RBP is call-preserved.

It happens to work because the CRT code that calls `main` apparently doesn't use RBP after main returns. Similar to what Jester pointed out about the fact that printf happens to only care about the copy of the variadic arg in RDX, not in XMM1.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170#varargs)

---

#### Just for fun, I was curious how efficiently this can be done.

Turns out, just 4 FP instructions that actually operate on FP values, not counting loads and zeroing a register, if we use FMA and AVX1.  Otherwise 6.

You don't need a separate `fabs(x)`, `x^2 - 1` will be negative only if `|x| <= 1.0`. A number close to 1.0 but not exactly equal will get farther away from 1.0 when squaring, so FP rounding error won't result in `x^2 - 1 >= 0.0` for any numbers where |x| < 1.0`, even with rounding modes other than the default (nearest, with even mantissa as a tiebreak).

So perhaps compute `x^2 - 1` in XMM0, then `pshufd xmm1, xmm0, 0b01010101` (duplicate the high dword of the double) / `psrad xmm1, 31` to broadcast the sign bit of the double (there is no `psraq` 64-bit arithmetic right-shift).

Then `andnps xmm1, xmm0` to zero it (AND with all-zero bits) or leave it unmodified (AND with all-one bits) according to the inverse of that sign bit. I guess do the `pshufd` / `psrad` before the `copysign`, but the `andnps` after. (There's an `andnpd` instruction but it does the same as `andnps` but is 1 byte longer in machine code, so it's pointless.)

I had a look at GCC/clang compiler output ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMQAJlIOAMngMmABy7gBGmMTeGqQADqgKhLYMzm4e3nEJSQIBQaEsEVFeMZaY1slCBEzEBKnunj6l5QKV1QS5IeGR0RZVNXXpjX3tgZ0F3cUAlBaorsTI7Bzos2H0ANT8qBDLrquYa6qTAKQA7ABCRxoAgmu3a3hUaxCqRwDMjm8AIgC0XAB0Gkma1OF2ud3Ba2ImAIcwYay4a2%2BBwAVC9XqCbndTp81phaEp7o9nsDXtgvvCAUCQZdMRDIdDYSjVIj4W8MeDsbj8ftqWC6fSYcQ4Ro2TSOSdPjTsVLrkcvK9Asg3FgSY4WEwCAg/gg3mTrjs9mswtVtit1ocpecxXcDeavCwEeTVKiWVxRXzbg8nqp7Y7SeTAcCrR6IVDBXC0LEAJ6JYAMZ6%2B0gHY7o623Tl4gm82mhhlCtYi1Mh6WyiUcaa0TgAVl4ng4WlIqE4jjWClm8x58p4pAImnL0wA1iBXgA2P5VqsADhHkgAnBouJOTlwvLPXvpOJJa33G5xeAoQDFe/Xy6Q4LAYFBLxAkGgWLE6JFyJQ7w/6FFkErDMAuCONDEsAANzwBYADU8EwAB3AB5WJGE4bsaFoAhIgPCAwh3MJAmqKMEN4LDmGIKNoLCbQymPbs7zYQRoIYWhcJPUgsHVIxxEY/AoXKQDMAPRjMFUMpXBQvDyEEPEd1oPAwmIHDnCwESCGIPAWDw6YqAMYAFHAqDYPg7heH4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdRGN0Lh9G/EBTGMcxJLCA9IGmVBYhsAReO%2BaDXkRAB1MRaGC/jFKYW5vioKgmAUAhvnVTV9zxcjknsBgnBceo9H8UZ8kKPR4kSHyUhy9I7JK7IGA6QrujspoytafoKs8Rq0uaBgWpGPIuiiRrhgGdrejaOr%2BokaY2zmBY9EgwwCFgggAEkGH4VSNw4GtSDrBsmw4A5p2%2BGc1i/Ix4THDQASeXBCBIYEu0mXhjy0SZpgQTAmCwKIIEHEBJCrP5XlXE5Zy4WdJFeKGThOEdNq3UgVKrSQgckOdiihtdoekXbeH2/dDx7PtpnPRAUFQe9HzICgIFfKmUB/LwfCAkDMG0mC4LrRC6BQ4g0IwxiCJwkShaIkiyOsESqMYRa6IYhtmO/NiFbwTibG43iG34wThP00SUMrRjXJkoi5MWbtFOUjb1KYTT2d0rmDNkYzxDMwz5CUNQd10HwDCMRyzH0KT3N%2BxtvOSPyAuC0LwtUSLEVi%2BLEuShBUqsMrMuytIRvyvrxgGzJSuSYbiqyMrxvzvQmoqIa2qrzrmuGCuisGtoS9bmpm4aqb21muz5po7zVvW/SK2rbdGP2w6R2OyQ1mAT94S8P4vBu/AiGIB7Xi4J6iZPN7SA%2Br7ulDodkb%2BEcTg0YpJw0KsRwfpn10NhHcd3DgCaPYmx44LxeBUycrwAQ3yhqAsBdk374z3q9M814kCzAILEISz5aYUzfJEYIrBFiqCOidM6wALoAgBLwTA68SB4HQHod2LtTLSHdpZL2Nk5oyViBtQ221IGcGgkJJBBA1ioEeDgmeeC/YEN/EQjQTxnCU3fFvHez1v6H0%2Bt9SgP8EYqXEbOUGv4H66L0TjHcUCDxf33n9EcQC0ZcFeFWDQs5JwriXLYzarwJ57T3NA/sm0/47UMe4l6njuJ8wypIIAA%3D%3D)) for a function that takes a double and returns the value you want, for a simple branchy version like the problem description, and a copysign version. They do a bit more work than necessary, but clang does make fully branchless code for the copysign version, converting an `if (x*x - 1 >= 0)` into bitwise ops like I suggested, including `andnpd` to apply the condition.  So that's fun :)

It uses `xorpd`-zeroing + `cmpltsd` to actually compare against zero instead of arithmetic right shifts on the sign bit to get the same result, which is probably more efficient (xor-zeroing is very cheap, but `cmpltsd` competes for the same execution ports as other FP math).

I had a go at hand optimizing it myself, to see if without AVX we'd need many `movaps` register-copy instructions; turns out not.  Just one if we were doing this in a loop, not reloading a constant into a fresh register each time.

I'm using Linux not Windows, so the calling convention for library functions (printf/scanf) uses different registers, and there's no shadow space.  I didn't optimize away the shadow space so it'd be easier to convert back to Windows.

```
; tested and works on x86-64 GNU/Linux; for Windows only the scanf/printf calls need to change
; nasm -felf64 foo.asm && gcc -no-pie foo.o

extern printf, scanf
global main
default rel

section .rodata             ; read only data.  Windows calls this .rdata
  signmask: dq 1<<63        ; aka -0.0
  one: dq 1.0
  
  in_fmt:  db "%lf", 0
  out_fmt: db "Result: %g", 10, 0      ; %g to output numbers close to 0 in scientific notation.
  

section .text
main:
;  mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging.  Not needed, and not sufficient for backtracing through main on its own.
  ;scanf()
  sub rsp, 40
  lea rdi, [in_fmt]
  lea rsi, [rsp+32]      ; scan into stack space, no need for a global
  xor  eax, eax          ; x86-64 System V not Windows: AL = 0 xmm args
  call scanf
  movsd   xmm1, [rsp+32]

;  pcmpeqd xmm2, xmm2
;  psllq   xmm2, 63               ; sign-bit mask, -0.0
  movsd   xmm2, [signmask]       ; or use a memory constant
  andps   xmm2, xmm1             ; sign bit of x

  mulsd   xmm1, xmm1
  subsd   xmm1, [one]           ; x*x - 1.0

  orps    xmm2, xmm1            ; copysign from original x

  xorps   xmm0, xmm0
  cmpltsd xmm0, xmm1            ; 0 < x*x-1   aka x*x-1 > 0.0 which is also |x| > 1.0.   This produces a +0.0 result instead of -0.0 for an input of -1.0
  andps   xmm0, xmm2            ; zero if |x| < 1.0, else the copysign result

.print:
    lea rdi, [out_fmt]
    mov eax, 1          ; x86-64 System V not Windows: AL = 1 xmm arg
    ; first FP arg in XMM0 for x86-64 SysV.
    ; on Windows it would go in XMM1 and RDX because it's the second overall arg.
    call printf
    add rsp, 40
    
  xor eax, eax
  ret
```

With AVX + FMA we can save a couple more instructions

```
  vmovsd   xmm1, [rsp+32]            ; x

  vandpd  xmm2, xmm1, [signmask]     ; xmm2 = sign bit of x, leaving xmm1 unmodified
                ; signmask is probably 16-byte aligned, that's why I put it at the start of .rdata.  We don't care that the top 8 bytes are of this 16-byte load, as long as they don't fault e.g. by going off the end of a page.
                ; we don't *need* 16-byte alignment with AVX instructions, so I didn't use align 16

  vfmsub213sd xmm1, xmm1, [one]  ; x*x - 1.0   like mulsd / subsd but without rounding error between mul and sub
  vorps     xmm2,xmm2, xmm1         ; copysign from original x

  vxorpd    xmm0,xmm0, xmm0         ; zero a register to blend with.
  vblendvpd xmm0, xmm2, xmm0, xmm1  ; pick values from xmm2 (copysign) and xmm0 (0.0) according to sign bit in xmm2 (x^2-1)
                                      ; 1 uop on Zen.  2 uops on Intel before Ice Lake, 3 uops on Alder Lake.
```

[`vblendvpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blendvpd) saves an instruction (`vcmpltsd`), but can be slower on Intel, especially on Alder Lake E-cores (4 uops).  https://uops.info/. The non-VEX version (SSE4.1 `blendvpd` which takes the blend-control in XMM0 implicitly) is only 1 uop on Skylake and later (including Alder Lake P and E cores).

I think we could re-arrange things to have x^2-1 in XMM0, and the two sources in other registers.  The non-AVX version, `blendvpd xmm1, xmm2`, has to overwrite one of the inputs, so that's fine for Windows where we want the result in XMM1 anyway, not XMM0.

We're not using the upper halves of any YMM registers, so it would be safe to mix 128-bit AVX instructions and legacy SSE without transition penalties.

We could save another register if we don't mind returning `-0.0` instead of `+0.0` for negative inputs, using `x & signmask` result from `vandpd`, which is basically `copysign(0.0, x)`.  The problem specified returning `0`, which is distinct from `-0.0` in IEEE FP math, even though it compares equal to it.

---

Both versions work correctly around the boundary near +-1.0; the FMA is just an efficiency boost; we don't need its extra precision of not rounding the `x*x` to the nearest `double` before subtracting.  With inputs near 1 + [DBL_EPSILON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) (the smallest number larger than 1.0 that's representable as a double), we get an output of 2x DBL_EPSILON (2x 2.22e-16 is about 4.44e-16), e.g.

```
$ ./a.out
1.00000000000000012
Result: 4.44089e-16
$ ./a.out
-1.00000000000000012
Result: -4.44089e-16
```

`(1+epsilon)^2 - 1` is `(1^2 + 2*epsilon + epsilon^2) - 1`, and epsilon squared is lost in rounding error.

My FMA/blendvpd version has one bug: with an input of `-1.0`, it produces `-0` instead of `+0`.  The correct result of `1.0 - 1.0` is +1.0 in the default rounding mode.

```
$ ./sse-compare
-1.0
Result: 0

$ ./fma-blend
-1.0          
Result: -0

$ ./fma-blend
-0.99999999999999 
Result: 0
```

The `cmpltsd` version avoids that by checking for `|x| > 1.0` instead of `|x| >= 1.0` ([`cmpltsd` vs. `cmplesd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpsd)).  Since `x^2-1` is mathematically 0 at that point, getting it from forcing the result to zero works just as well as from the computation result.  Better in fact for FP math if we care about the sign of zero, since we're playing tricks with `copysign` instead of actually doing `1 - x^2` or `x^2 - 1` which would both produce `+0.0`.

But if we want to use the sign bit of the `x^2 - 1` subtraction directly, that's like a `|x| >= 1.0` comparison.

---

As Bruce Dawson wrote in an excellent [series of articles about FP math](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/), borrowing a phrase from Douglas Adams:

> [Floating-point] math is hard.
>
> You just won’t believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly hard it is. I mean, you may think it’s difficult to calculate when trains from Chicago and Los Angeles will collide, but that’s just peanuts to floating-point math.

I spent about a couple hours playing around with this to make "simpler" and more efficient asm than just naively branching the way the problem description is stated.  I'm pretty confident both versions are correct now, but I only caught the `-0.0` output from the FMA version pretty late in writing this answer while playing with the `vblendvpd` version, and only at that point noticed a mistake in the comment on the compare version, that it was actually doing `|x| > 1.0` or `|x| <= 1.0`, not `|x| >= 1.0` like I'd thought I was doing. :P

Being clever with floating point math is often possible, and often can lead to more efficient code, but being 100% certain it's right in all cases requires [careful testing](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/theres-only-four-billion-floatsso-test-them-all/).

(I haven't tested with +-Infinity inputs, but both versions should work, producing an infinity of the correct sign.  With NaN inputs, we should get a NaN output with the sign of the input.  Or +0.0 depending on how we compare.  `0.0 < NaN` is false, so I think all NaN inputs will give a zero output for any NaN input.)